# What is the automated testing tool that helps in verfying the object level code of an application?

Tags: automated-testing

I would like to know about the automated testing tool that are used to verify the object level code of an application, an application that interacts with the hardware and in particular the testing tool that is used to test application in vehicle launch station.

Comment: Not able to understand what you are asking. please describe your question properly. so one can help.